# Bootstrap 5, full viewport + responsive bg

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am able to use 2 full viewport `div` using the following code. Sadly, when I try to add an HD (1366x768) image as the background for the first full viewport `div`, it breaks everything. I tried to use `img-fluid` as mentioned in [Bootstrap 5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/images/)

I am using the default HTML template provided by getbootstrap.com as starting template.

It would be nice to know how to make the background image responsive and still keep the 2 full viewport sections intact. Please feel free to ask any other info you would want to know. Thanks.

```
 <div class="container-fluid px-0 overflow-hidden">

      <div class="w-100 vh-100 bg1">

<!-- need to add a responsive background using an SVG file with HD size here -->
```

`<img src="bg.svg" class="img-fluid" alt="bg"> <!-- breaks everything -->`

```
     </div> 
 
<!-- 2-->


    <div class="w-100 vh-100 bg2"> 

        <div class="row bg3 text-center">
            
                
                    <div class="col pd50">


                        <div class="row row-cols-2">


                            <div class="col pd20 and"><i class="fab fa-android fa-5x green"></i><p>Android apps</p></div>
                            <div class="col pd20 ang"><i class="fab fa-angular fa-5x red"></i><p>Single Page Apps</p></div>
                          
                          
                            <div class="col pd20 chr"><i class="fab fa-chrome fa-5x blue"></i><p>Web Apps</p></div>
                            <div class="col pd20 dok"><i class="fab fa-docker fa-5x bluesky"></i><p>Cloud based apps</p></div>
                          
                        </div> 

                      
             
                    </div>                
                      
              
              <div class="col pd50">
                <i class="fab fa-chromecast fa-10x blue"></i><hr>One website, which works on Android, iPhone, iPad, Tablets, Laptops, Desktop and all. Fast, responsive, modern and secure framework.
                
              </div>
             
              <div class="align-item-center text-center pdbot50">

                <a href="mailto:jeeve@gmail.com"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">@gmail</button></a>
              </div>

            </div>

         
                        
          </div>

        </div>
```

CSS in case you need to refer

```
/* Google Fonts */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@300&display=swap');

body {
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}


.fullbg { 
    background-image: url(/home.svg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
   
      }

.landpg {
    background-image: url(/home.svg) fixed; 
 
   
}

  
#grad {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #0ca8cc,#9700ff);
  }


.bg1 {
    background-color: #007cff;
    color: white;
}

.bg2 {
    background-color: #00ff64;
    color: black;
}

.bg3 {
    background-color: white;
}

.pd10 {
    padding: 10px;
}

.pd20 {
    padding: 20px;
}

.pd50 {
    padding: 50px;
}

.pt50 {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.pdbot50 {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.marleft10 {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.green {
    color: #1fec1f;
}

.blue {
    color: blue;
}

.red {
    color: red;
}

.bluesky {
    color: skyblue;
}

.white {
    color: white;
   }

/* hover */

.and:hover {
    background-color: rgba(37, 147, 161, 0.212);
}

.ang:hover {
    background-color: rgba(37, 147, 161, 0.212);
}

.chr:hover {
    background-color: rgba(37, 147, 161, 0.212);
}

.dok:hover {
    background-color: rgba(37, 147, 161, 0.212);
}
```

screen cast. When I add the responsive image code form Bootstrap docs everything breaks as seen in GIF below
[image]

Comment: can you provide image or snippet of your problem

Comment: Hi @AnkitTiwari please find the screencast attached https://i.imgur.com/26QUgNo.gif the image overshoots the viewport, the second div also shows problems when using the img code I got from getbootstrap.com

Comment: It would be nice to know the image size

Comment: Hi @Zim it's 1366x768 - HD screen size. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found issue you have to remove `vh-100` from your `div` which wraps your image check below snippet it's working fine let me know if there is any changes
i have added a class named as `custom` to set 100% image width and  to treat image as block element. You can remove if you don't want and add yours

```css
/* Google Fonts */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@300&display=swap');

body {
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}

.custom{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin:auto;
}

.fullbg { 
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642632823-8f785ba67e45?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=889&q=80) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
   
      }

.landpg {
    background-image: url() fixed; 
 
   
}

  
#grad {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #0ca8cc,#9700ff);
  }


.bg1 {
    background-color: #007cff;
    color: white;
}

.bg2 {
    background-color: #00ff64;
    color: black;
}

.bg3 {
    background-color: white;
}

.pd10 {
    padding: 10px;
}

.pd20 {
    padding: 20px;
}

.pd50 {
    padding: 50px;
}

.pt50 {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.pdbot50 {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.marleft10 {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.green {
    color: #1fec1f;
}

.blue {
    color: blue;
}

.red {
    color: red;
}

.bluesky {
    color: skyblue;
}

.white {
    color: white;
   }

/* hover */

.and:hover {
    background-color: rgba(37, 147, 161, 0.212);
}

.ang:hover {
    background-color: rgba(37, 147, 161, 0.212);
}

.chr:hover {
    background-color: rgba(37, 147, 161, 0.212);
}

.dok:hover {
    background-color: rgba(37, 147, 161, 0.212);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="container-fluid px-0 overflow-hidden">

      <div class="w-100 bg1">
      <!----problem was here removed vh-100 from above div------>

<!-- need to add a responsive background using an SVG file with HD size here -->
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642632823-8f785ba67e45?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=889&q=80" class="img-fluid custom" alt="bg"> <!-- breaks everything -->

     </div> 
 
<!-- 2-->


    <div class="w-100 bg2"> 

        <div class="row bg3 text-center">
            
                
                    <div class="col pd50">


                        <div class="row row-cols-2">


                            <div class="col pd20 and"><i class="fab fa-android fa-5x green"></i><p>Android apps</p></div>
                            <div class="col pd20 ang"><i class="fab fa-angular fa-5x red"></i><p>Single Page Apps</p></div>
                          
                          
                            <div class="col pd20 chr"><i class="fab fa-chrome fa-5x blue"></i><p>Web Apps</p></div>
                            <div class="col pd20 dok"><i class="fab fa-docker fa-5x bluesky"></i><p>Cloud based apps</p></div>
                          
                        </div> 

                      
             
                    </div>                
                      
              
              <div class="col pd50">
                <i class="fab fa-chromecast fa-10x blue"></i><hr>One website, which works on Android, iPhone, iPad, Tablets, Laptops, Desktop and all. Fast, responsive, modern and secure framework.
                
              </div>
             
              <div class="align-item-center text-center pdbot50">

                <a href="mailto:jeeve@gmail.com"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">@gmail</button></a>
              </div>

            </div>

         
                        
          </div>

        </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Almost there, but when used with the Font Awesome icons, the grid in the second viewport `div` breaks. Please see : https://imgur.com/deEDDV9

Comment: Hello @user227495 i not getting whare it's breaks it's look fine can you explain that you want spacing or what

Comment: Hi, what is below the Cast icon is missing. Only a part of it is available. It happens only when I add font awesome kit to it. I simply copy-pasted your code, linked the CSS and added the FA kit. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I have no problem adding upvote or accepting the answer. But please understand that as you see in the screencast in the comment for this answer that the text under the cast icon is only partially visible. I would kindly request you to check with a Font Awesome kit, so that you can see that the 2nd viewport <div> 's grid breaks. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello @user227495 check now actually setting `vh-100` it will give you viewport  height which is your scrren height  so it was not visible below viewport so i removed `vh-100` you should always use height 100% let me know if still there is problem